# SAML Identity Provider with a WS-Federation Service Provider

Tags: web-services, authentication, saml, ws-federation

How easy or difficult it is for a SAML Identity Provider to work with a WS-Federation Service Provider? Are there tools that will allow a SAML IDp to work with any Service Provider despite the technology used?
Which side will have the most effort?

Thank you!

Comment: Q1 depends on who you ask, Q2 is a library or software recommendation, which is off topic, here but there is an SE for that, Q3 depends on things I can't imagine.

Comment: Q1 Well my question is to Service Providers. Q2 What's an SE? Q3 ok...

Comment: Stack Exchange, SO is one of many Stack Exchanges. The software rec one is here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ That is where you ask, which Service Provider should I buy, or which library should I use/buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each IDP only supports that protocol, then no.

Most IDP e.g. ADFS support both so can act as a bridge.

**Update:**

ADFS sits in the middle as a broker. It can talk SAML to SAML sites and WS-Fed to WS-Fed sites.
So you now have three STS: SAML, WS-Fed and ADFS. ADFS essentially translates between the two.

The only "tools"  that are available are the stacks for SAML and WS-Fed e.g.

- WIF for WS-Fed
- [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html)

Comment: As am very new on this topic can you please elaborate? You mean No there are no tools? Where will ADFS be installed on the Identity Provider side or the Service Provider side? I hope I make sense to you...thank you

Comment: Can ADFS work with all web users or with only Active Directory users within an organisation?

Comment: ADFS works with AD on premise. However, it can integrate with Azure Active Directory in the cloud. AAD also supports both WS-Fed and SAML. There are others e.g. Ping, OpenAM that support both.

Comment: thank you very much I think now I am on the right track!